# Trying to use the @transient variable in a different class

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project that is writing to the database using Hibernate.

I have an Abstract POJO for the model

**Removed code**

There isn't anything special going on in the subclasses. But I have a controller class that I'm trying to modify some of the data. I want to use the Transient variable, but its not letting me. I am doing this in the other class

**REMOVED CODE**

Then I call an iterator to take what is in the database and add it to the map. This all is working fine.

My main question, 
When I do temp.setDescription...it isn't saving a description element in the temp object. Therefore it isn't passing to the map.

Any suggestions? I hope I provided enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the variable I needed in the hashCode in my model. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're never putting "temp" into the map...  the only code you have that puts items in the map is:

```
computerMap.put(hardware.getUuid(), hardware);
```

For the case where it's a new object, you instantiate a new computer and assign it to `temp` not `hardware` so any new computers will never get in the map.

Comment: I apologize, that was me mis typing because I did change the variable names. That should be computerMap.put(hardware.getUuid(), temp); I will change it.